# Server not starting when called by a cluster fork with import

Tags: node.js, express, node-cluster

I'm tryng to make a server with muitiple workers, but the server never starts when I use the import statment. If i put the code directly inside the worker function they run with no problems.

code with import:

```js
import os from 'os'
import cluster from 'cluster'
import { initJobs } from './jobs'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import 'express-async-errors'
import http from 'http'

import routes from './routes/index.routes'
import { socket } from './socket'
import { startDatabase } from './db'
import errorCatcher from './errors'
dotenv.config()

import { logSuccess, logError } from './utils/log'
// initJobs(io)

const runPrimaryProcess = () => {
    const processesCount = os.cpus().length

    logSuccess('server', `Primary ${process.pid} is running`)

    logSuccess('server', `Forking Server with ${processesCount} processes \n`)

    for (let index = 0; index < processesCount; index++) cluster.fork()

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, _signal) => {
        if (code !== 0 && !worker.exitedAfterDisconnect) {
            logError('cluster', `Worker ${worker.process.pid} died... scheduling another one!`)

            cluster.fork()
        }
    })
}

const runWorkerProcess = async () => {
    logSuccess('worker', `Worker ${process.pid} started`)
    await import('./server')
}

cluster.isPrimary ? runPrimaryProcess() : runWorkerProcess()
```

server.ts:

```js
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import 'express-async-errors'
import http from 'http'

import routes from './routes/index.routes'
import { socket } from './socket'
import { startDatabase } from './db'
import { logSuccess } from './utils/log'
import errorCatcher from './errors'
// import { initJobs } from './jobs'

export const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(routes)

const server = http.createServer(app)

startDatabase()

const io = socket(server)

errorCatcher(app)
// initJobs(io)

const port = process.env.DEV_LOG_PORT || 3333

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    server.listen(port, () => {
        logSuccess('server', `started on port ${port} `)
    })
}
```

all the works are instaced, showing the pid correctly, but server not start.(console.logs inside the server.ts does not show as well)

When I put the server.ts code inside `runWorkerProcess` function, all runs correctly.